# ¿Como enviar datos de un Fragment a otro Fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo creada una aplicación donde creo 3 Fragments los cuales los visualizo con tabs y quiero enviar información de un fragment a otro.. pero no se en que estoy mal ya que no me marca error de código, pero cuando  doy clic en el boton enviar la aplicación se detiene.

1. **primerFragment**

   - visualiza solo unos CardView,
2. **segundoFragment**

   - 2 EditText y un boton **enviar** para enviar al **TercerFragment**
3. **TercerFragmetn**

   - **ListView** para recibir datos del **segundoFragment**

**Clase SegundoBlankFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_segundo_blank, container, false);

        editText1 = view.findViewById(R.id.editTex1);
        editText2 = view.findViewById(R.id.editTex2);
        btn1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createNewPerson();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

private void createNewPerson() {
        if (!editText1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Temp person = new Temp(editText1.getText().toString(), editText2.getText().toString() );
            Tem2.createPerson(person);
        }
    }
```

**Clase interface Tem2** la cual solo hace referencia a la clase Temp 2 que solo tiene 2 String text1 y text2 con su respectivo constructor, gets y sets

```
public interface Tem2 {
    void createPerson(Temp person);
}
```

**Clase TercerFragment** donde se supone que se debe visualizar una lista de los elementos que envió desde el **TercerFragment**

```
private List<Temp> persons;
private ListView listView;
private adapterTemp adapter;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tercer_blank, container, false);
        persons = new ArrayList<Temp>();
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewPerson);
        adapter = new adapterTemp(getContext(),R.layout.list_view_temp, persons);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

public void addPerson(Temp person) {
        this.persons.add(person);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

---

**logcat**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.yordy.richard.calculadora.SegundoBlankFragment cannot be cast to com.yordy.richard.calculadora.TercerBlankFragment

at com.yordy.richard.calculadora.MainActivity.createPerson(MainActivity.java:111)
        at com.yordy.richard.calculadora.SegundoBlankFragment.createNewPerson(SegundoBlankFragment.java:59)
        at com.yordy.richard.calculadora.SegundoBlankFragment.access$000(SegundoBlankFragment.java:19)
        at com.yordy.richard.calculadora.SegundoBlankFragment$1.onClick(SegundoBlankFragment.java:46)
```

En la linea 111 del  **MainActivity** esta lo sigueinte

```
TercerBlankFragment fragment = (TercerBlankFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(PERSON_LIST_FRAGMENT);
```

lo que  esta dentro del get es

```
public static final int PERSON_LIST_FRAGMENT = 1;
```

Clase **Pageadapter**

```
private int numberOfTabs;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return new PrimerBlankFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SegundoBlankFragment();
            case 2:
                return new TercerBlankFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: La forma más sencilla en que lo hice, fue pedir el dato en el constructor del Fragment que va a recibir el dato. No creo que sea muy ético, pero me funcionó.

Comment: @Andrés probablemente no, pero una forma de hacerlo es tal como se indica en la respuesta que se marca como correcta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La comunicación entre `Fragments` que dependen de un `Activity` debe ser hecho a través del `Activity` y no en forma directa.

Para la comunicación entre `Fragment` y `Activity`, si bien se puede hacer a través de castear `getActivity()` en el `Fragment` a la clase del `Activity` (por ejemplo `MainActivity`) la forma recomendada de hacerlo es a través de `interfaces`, que utilizan los `Fragments` para hacer callbacks al `Activity`, y a su vez, el `Activity` las implementa para responder a los `Fragments`.

Este cubriría lo básico de comunicación, abajo un poco más sobre el tema.

Luego tenemos que la app utiliza `ViewPager` para mostrar los diferentes `Fragments` de la app. `ViewPager` tiene dos cosas a tener en cuenta:

1) Maneja el ciclo de vida de los `Fragments`. Es decir que basado en el o los `Fragments` que le pasamos cuando lo inicializamos, se queda con la clase, y después mata, crea, y reemplaza instancias según le convenga. Esto trae una complejidad si queremos en algún momento poder invocar algo sobre el `Fragment` dado que si nos guardamos una instancia para después, tal vez no sea la misma que se muestre en pantalla dentro de un rato.

2) El `ViewPager` prepara los `Views` de antemano antes de que el `Fragment` sea visible, con lo que si dependemos de por ejemplo `onResume()` para mostrar algún dato actualizado, ese `onResume()` se puede llamar cuando tal vez ni siquiera estén dadas las condiciones para poder calcular la actualización de la pantalla.

Para resolver el punto 1, en lugar de tratar de quedarnos con una instancia de los `Fragments` al crearlos por primera vez, en el adapter, hacemos un `override` del método `instantiateItem`, que se llama cuando el `ViewPager` crea una nueva instancia de nuestro `Fragment`, y tomando la nueva instancia reemplazamos la anterior en nuestra referencia.

El segundo punto lo resolvemos utilizando `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)` que es un método del Fragment y es llamado por el `ViewPager` con `true` cuando el mismo va a ser mostrado en pantalla. Entonces aprovechamos este call back para hacer las actualzaciones de último minuto antes de que Fragment sea mostrado. (Supuestamente este método se llama de forma correcta, en varsiones anteriores podía ser llamado con el activity en null y era necesario hacer algunos checkeos extra).

Volviendo al tema de la comunicación entre Activity y Fragment. Cuando es el `Fragment` que le envía algo al `Activity` de parte del usuario, y asumiendo que es en forma interactiva con la pantalla, no hay mayores problemas porque el `Activity` esta funcionando y el `Fragment` también. Cuando es el `Activity` el que tendría que mandarle algo al `Fragment` surge el problema de que el `Fragment` puede no estar listo cuando el `Activity` le quiere enviar un mensaje. Entonces la forma en que lo resuelvo es hacer que el `Fragment` le pida el dato al `Activity` cuando el `Fragment` está listo para recibirlo (y en todo caso también puede verificar que el Activity tabmién está listo para mandarlo).

Abajo un ejemplo de todo esto:

**Layouts:**

*Fragment Uno*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soy Fragment 1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
        android:text="Enviar Fecha a Fragment 2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Fragment Dos*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Soy Fragment 2"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHoraActual"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Main Activity*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java**

*Main Activity*

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements FragmentUno.FragmentUnoListener, FragmentDos.FragmentDosListener {

    private String laFechaActualSegunFragment1;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private TabLayout tabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        viewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Fragment fragmentUno = new FragmentUno();
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentUno,"Frag Uno");
        Fragment fragmentDos = new FragmentDos();
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragmentDos,"Frag Dos");

        tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(viewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0)),0);
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(viewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(1)),1);


        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
               viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           }
           @Override
           public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}

           @Override
           public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
       });

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFechaActualIngresada(String horaActual) {
        this.laFechaActualSegunFragment1 = horaActual;
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHoraActual() {
        return this.laFechaActualSegunFragment1;
    }
}
```

*ViewPager Adapter*

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    protected final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    protected final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    protected final HashMap<Integer,Fragment> currentInstances = new HashMap<>();
    protected FragmentManager fm;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.fm = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        currentInstances.put(position, createdFragment);
        return createdFragment;
    }

    public Fragment getCurrentIntance(int position){
        return currentInstances.get(position);
    }
}
```

*Fragment Uno (El que envía un dato a Fragment Dos)*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Date;

public class FragmentUno extends Fragment {

    private Button btnEnviar;
    private FragmentUnoListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof FragmentUnoListener){
            this.listener = (FragmentUnoListener) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_fragment1_layout,null);
        btnEnviar = viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
        btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String fechaActual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
                listener.onFechaActualIngresada(fechaActual);
            }
        });
        return viewRoot;
    }

    public static interface FragmentUnoListener{
        public void onFechaActualIngresada(String horaActual);
    }
}
```

*Fragment Dos (El que recibe un dato ingresado desde Fragment Uno)*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentDos extends Fragment {

    private FragmentDosListener listener;

    TextView tvHoraActual;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof  FragmentDosListener){
            this.listener = (FragmentDosListener) context;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View viewRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_fragment2_layout,null);

        tvHoraActual = viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.tvHoraActual);

        return viewRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            String horaActual = listener.getHoraActual();
            tvHoraActual.setText(horaActual);
        }
    }

    public static interface FragmentDosListener{
        public String getHoraActual();
    }
}
```

Comment: Elimine mis comentarios anteriores debido a que encontré mi error.. ahora intentare que mis datos se pongan en lista tal como quiero que se visualicen. para eso utilizare un `ListView`Cualquier consejo para hacerlo lo acepto con gusto..

Comment: Si podes te sugiero usar RecyclerView en lugar de ListView.

Comment: utilizo un RecyclerView en mi fragmentUno el cual lo lleno de varios CardView y tengo entendido que se tiene que hacer una clase Adapter para dicho Recycler y con un ListView solo se utiliza un arreglo para llenarlo o segun el ejemplo que vi.. solo que yo utilizo un Array de tipo Persona para llenar ese ListView solo que ahora con tu metodo `setUserVisibleHint` que tengo entendido es donde asignas el texto al TextView no se donde llenar mi ListView

Comment: ListView también usa un adapter. Al adapter el pasas el array con los datos. Si los datos cambian o pueden cambiar cada vez que visitas el gragment, un buen lugar para hacerlo es setUservisibleHint, desde ahi podes llamar un metodo privado que lo haga en todo caso.