# Cómo puedo instanciar objetos de un fragmento al Acivity?

Tags: android-studio

Vi algo así pero no me funciona de ninguna de las dos formas.
Tomando en cuenta que tengo el fragmento llamado `DatosEncargado` donde tengo el objeto `numero_incidente`?
Y en el **`main`** algo asi?

```
DatosEncargados d= new DAtosEncargados();
d.numero:incidente.getText,toString();
```

Comment: La pregunta como está es muy genérica. Comentá un poco lo que estás queriendo hacer y puntualmente que es lo que no te está saliendo. Por otro lado, fijate que en el editor de la pregunta hay una llaves que te permiten marcar el código fuente en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, lo que quiero es utilizar objetos que están declarados en el fragmento DatosEncargado en el MainActivity.

Comment: Fijate esta respuesta que escribí hace unos días a ver si te ayuda. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204586/como-enviar-datos-de-un-fragment-a-otro-fragment/204662#204662. Lo relevante para vos seria la comunicación entre activity y fragment con interfaces

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio @YunDryNaVarro te recomiendo revisar [ask] para mejorar las preguntas y sean entendibles para la comunidad, de esta forma obtendrás excelentes respuestas.Agrega el Fragment  DatosEncargado  No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio.